# How to return the first object of array in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to return the first object of an array, how do I achieve this.

```
{ products && products.map((product,i)=>(
       <div key={i} >
          <h6>{product.name} - {product.category.name}</h6>
          <p className="mb-0"> {product.price} returns in {product.duration} months</p>
       </div>
   ))
 }
```

Comment: Don't use `products` (an array), set a variable `product` to `products[0]` and use that.

Comment: As Heretic Monkey says, get the product item first   let product = Array.isArray(products) && products.length > 0 && products[0], and avoid to get props this way  products[0].name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not interested in mapping the whole array, just getting first item, you can use index instead:

```
{ products && products[0] && (
       <div>
          <h6>{products[0].name} - {products[0].category.name}</h6>
          <p className="mb-0"> {products[0].price} returns in {products[0].duration} months</p>
       </div>)
   ))
 }
```

**Note:** By the way, `[]` is considered as truthy value in JS so you should use `!!products.length` instead of `products`